# Maintaining split window proportions when resizing window frame in gvim

Tags: vim

I use gvim primarily on Windows with window splitting (:vsp, etc).  I'd like them to maintain their proportions when I resize the frame (the GUI window).  Is there an easy way to do this?

I.e., when I use :vsp, both left and right windows occupy 50% of the frame.  Say I make the frame twice as wide.  Now the left window is much smaller - it's split 25%/75%.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
:au VimResized * wincmd =
```

When you resize the windows, `:wincmd =` will be called.